# Load balancing server

Tags: load-balancing

I would like to know about load balancing servers.

I am having an application which is having load balanced server. 
When i made some changes to the data, in my application how it is taking effect?
Also, when we restart the application , what are all the steps that are happening, to a load balanced server?

Answer (score 1):

well, the load balancer is separate from the application code, basically it is just routing the requests to one of a number of set up servers (a.k.a. downstream servers, for instance web application servers, apache/nginx+php, etc) that handles the actual request. So to update the application (i.e. java servlet, JSP, PHP page, static HTML page, image, etc) all the downstream servers will have to be updated. As for data (i.e. articles, user database, etc) this will usually be stored in a database that all the downstream servers connect to

As for restarting the application, when you do that on each of the downstream servers it will temporarily be unable to service requests, the load balancer will thus get an "unable to connect" issue when trying to send requests to the server with the application being restarted, and will then try to send the request to the next server in the list of downstream servers. Depending on how the load balancer is set up it will automatically retry sending new requests to the previously restarted server and when the restarted downstream server is up again it will again service requests. So to update the applications you basically just update one downstream server at the time, as the other servers take over the load while it is restarted it will be no downtime, and the clients will be none the wiser

Is this a hardware appliance or at server running HAProxy/nginx/other?

Comment: I'm thinking you might want to check with whoever set up your load balancer before you do any updates though...